# Why datamover is not allowed to login in 3 tier mode in Peoplesoft?

Tags: peoplesoft

When I tried to login to PeopelSoft datamover its gave me the below error.
[DataMover can be run in 2 tier mode only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1utcR.png)

Why it is not allowed to run in 3 tier mode ?

Answer (score 3):

This is because it is executing at the database level.  Its just a form of a SQL Query tool.  That's why you can execute straight SQL in a DMS.  3 tier connection is to the application server, it has nothing to do with DMS.